# Volitional form + かと

Tags: grammar, particle-と, volitional-form, embedded-question

> それから、少し手足を伸ば**そうかと**、道路のむかい側にあるパン屋まで歩いて買物に行くことにした。
> After that he stretched out a little and decided to go to the bread shop on the opposite side of the street.

First of all I'm not sure if he stretches and then goes shopping or whether he uses the walk to the bread shop as a means of stretching.

Regarding 伸ばそうかと I'm assuming we have a volitional form + か + と. My first inclination was to treat と as the conditional and get "Upon stretching he went shopping". But that leaves no place for the volitional or the か. This has to be wrong.

My second guess is that this is an abbreviation of 手足を伸ばそうかと思って "he thought he would stretch out and *go shopping*". But I still don't understand the purpose of か. Why is there any element of questioning in this?

Comment: Where did you get the original translation? Did you make it? It looks wrong to me. I agree with your second guess.

Comment: Isn't it 足をのばそうか instead of 手足?

Comment: @JimmyYang It's from the first Harry Potter book, translated into Japanese. I wouldn't be surprised if the translation had some issues. Wait, do you mean the English translation looks wrong? That would be entirley my fault.

Comment: @sundowner It is definitely  手足 but, see my comment to JimmyYang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in thinking そうかと is そうかと思って.

The relevant meanings of か are [the following](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8B/#jn-34861)

> ４ 勧誘・依頼の意を表す。「そろそろ行こう―」「手伝っていただけません―」
>
> ７ 引用した句の意味やある事実を確かめ、自分自身に言い聞かせる意を表す。「急がば回れ―」「そろそろ寝るとする―」

The particular instance can be understood as inviting oneself to stretch out, so 少し手足を伸ばそうかと would literally mean *thinking 'let's stretch out a little'*.

A few examples:

- 話題の新作を見ようと映画館に行った With the intention of watching the new film, I went to the theater.
- 残り物を食べようと冷蔵庫を開けた Trying to finish off the leftovers, I opened the fridge.

---

So it should be counted as another mistranslation.

- [誤訳・珍訳 日本語版ハリー・ポッターの不思議 Wiki](https://wikiwiki.jp/harrypotter/)

I've read neither the original nor the translation, but heard that Harry Potter was originally very minor, the huge success was not expected, and (accordingly) the translation is not of great quality.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little confused. "So it should be counted as another mistranslation" <-- which part are you saying is mistranslated, and why?

Comment: @user3856370 I mean if 'After that he stretched out a little' is the original, 少し手足を伸ばそうかと is not (really) a valid translation. Literally translating the English, it would be 少し手足を伸ばして/少し伸びをして. Or can the 'stretch out' mean something figuratively?

Comment: The English text was just my initial poor attempt at translating the Japanese. It's not the original English version. I'm trying to stay away from looking at that. If the Japanese sentence is fine as a standalone sentence then I'm happy. Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370 I see. FYI my initial response was that it is misusing 手足 instead of [足を延ばす](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%B6%B3%E3%82%92%E5%BB%B6%E3%81%B0%E3%81%99/#jn-3664), which seems to fit here.

Comment: @user3856370 - If [this](https://harry-potter-compendium.fandom.com/wiki/Bakery_in_Surrey) is the original text, it indeed seems a mistranslation, a rather bad one.

Comment: @user3856370 - And the Japanese sentence is not fine. It sounds like you are going to stretch out in the bakery.